# access request parameters in Rails 4.1 mailer preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

When I used to use the `MailView` gem to preview `ActionMailer` emails, I would access `@rack_env` to preview my emails under different conditions, e.g. delivery to a specific user or in a specific locale, or with specific inputs. With the new(ish) `ActionMailer::Preview` that instance variable isn't being set, and `params` doesn't exist. Does anyone know how to access the GET params to `/rails/mailers/:mailer/:action` with `ActionMailer::Preview`?

Ideally I'd like to be able to request `/rails/mailers/my_mailer/mymail?user_id=123` and use it like

```
class MyMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def mymail
    MyMailer.mymail(User.find(params[:user_id]))
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have access to `params`? How do you check it?

Comment: I checked it with a logging statement that said it wasn't defined. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: op is right, just use `binding.pry` and you'll see that `request` and `params` raise no method errors

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a simple solution to this and detailed it with a [blog post on extending ActionMailer](https://ruby.unicorn.tv/articles/access-url-request-parameters-from-actionmailer-preview). It's the easiest solution that I've found, my only concern would be how it may impact performance for other controllers.

```
# config/initializers/mailer_injection.rb

# This allows `request` to be accessed from ActionMailer Previews
# And @request to be accessed from rendered view templates
# Easy to inject any other variables like current_user here as well

module MailerInjection
  def inject(hash)
    hash.keys.each do |key|
      define_method key.to_sym do
        eval " @#{key} = hash[key] "
      end
    end
  end
end

class ActionMailer::Preview
  extend MailerInjection
end

class ActionMailer::Base
  extend MailerInjection
end

class ActionController::Base
  before_filter :inject_request

  def inject_request
    ActionMailer::Preview.inject({ request: request })
    ActionMailer::Base.inject({ request: request })
  end
end
```

Comment: This will get access to full `request` object. If you want only `params`, add this line `ActionMailer::Preview.inject({ params: request.params })` inside `inject_request` above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I use for a specific parameter (in my case to load a specific order), you could modify this to make it more generic and work for any or all parameters

It uses a class variable in the the XXXMailerPreview class, which shouldn't be a problem if you are running in dev. This is required because at least in Rails 5 the previews are shown in an IFrame and the url params added to the preview url are not passed to the IFrame urls.

Specifically this example code was for Abandoned Cart emails in Spree but it is also used for any order specific email preview

Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/abandonded_checkout_mailer

In `mailer_controller_decorator.rb` which you can load anyway you want after Rails is loaded

```
module MailerPreviewOrderNumber
  def set_order_number(order_number)
    @order_number = order_number
  end

  def get_order_number
    @order_number
  end

  def order_for_preview
    order_number = get_order_number
    order = Spree::Order.find_by(:number => order_number) if order_number.present?
    order = yield if order.blank?
    order
  end

end

Rails::MailersController.class_eval do
  before_action :save_order_number, only: [:preview]

  def save_order_number
    if @preview.present? && @preview.respond_to?(:set_order_number)
      @preview.set_order_number(params[:order]) if params[:order].present?
    end
  end
end
```

And in your XXXMailerPreview file

```
class AbandondedCheckoutMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  extend MailerPreviewOrderNumber

  def abandoned_checkout_email
    if Rails.env.development?
      order = self.class.order_for_preview do
        Spree::Order.order(updated_at: :desc).last
      end
      AbandonedCheckoutMailer.abandoned_checkout_email(order)
    end
  end
end
```

The block passed to `order_for_preview` is used in the case that no order param is provided to the preview URL the first time

Answer (score -1):

ActionMailer does not have access to the controller params, so pass the params you need as arguments instead:

```
class MyMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def mymail(user_id)
    MyMailer.mymail(User.find(user_id))
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
MyMailerPreview.mymail(params[:user_id]).deliver
```

Comment: That would work if I was defining a mailer, but I'm defining a preview as described at http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Previewing+emails. So in effect I am defining a controller, it's just I can't tell how / if ActionMailer::Preview exposes the request environment to the Preview subclass.

Comment: ActionMailer::Preview does not have access to any of the controller parameters (or much of anything else for that matter).  You'll have to pass the id as an argument.  Treat ActionMailer::Preview as if it was a a mailer.

Comment: Oh I see, so basically make my own mail preview controller. Well, that'll be a good solution if no one else has has a way to access those parameters. Thanks.

Comment: That's correct.  ActionMailer::Preview is designed to use for previewing your mailer **templates** not for displaying previews to your users.  The documentation you linked to spells out that you will need to add fake data under the "Previewing Emails" section.

Comment: if this PR https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20646 gets accepted by Rails passing params to mailer preview will be possible